# Application cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android

so basically I want to go from Adapter to fragment.

```
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();

                Fragment fragments = new Subject_Chapter_Fragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragments);
                ft.commit();
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
        at soft.gen.studentapp.Activities.adapter.Adapter_Subjects$1.onClick(Adapter_Subjects.java:45)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to get **application context** and then cast it to your activity instead

```
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext().getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: what view refers to?

Comment: I recommend you to pass your current activity to adapter while populating your list into the adapter(setadapter i.e)